# How do I take information from a TextView and store that in a SQLite database?

Tags: android-sqlite, textview, android

I am making a Chronometer app for android (basically a stopwatch) and I also need to create a database to store information. I have the time in a TextView and would like to take that and populate the database. So far the only thing I can put in the database is manually entered text through an EditText line. Any assistance on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You use  the same process a, that is use the `TextView`'s `getText` method and then convert the returned `charactersequence` to a `String` using the `charactersequence`'s `toString` method.

e.g.

```
String myDBData = myTextView.getText().toString();
```

Comment: I have tried that and it did not work. I even took that value and passed it to another activity to try to access the string value. But when I attempt to add data to the database, the insert function returns -1 and fails.

Answer (score 0):

So I had to go to my AVD manager and wipe the data from the emulator that I was using. I did everything correct, it was just Android Studio acting up. I do appreciate the downvote for not researching though :D

Comment: Odds on the reason why it worked after wiping the data is a common misconception that `onCreate` runs everytime whilst it only runs once when the database is created. Thus any changes made within the `onCreate` method, of the DatabaseHelper are only applied if the database is wiped or if the `onCreate` method is called otherwise (often `onUpgrade` will be written to call it, so increasing the version number can be a way of applying such changes.